there is already a datareader associated with this command which must be closed first
Hellow everyone, I hope someone can help me.
I have a vb.net console application that started giving me headaches just recently.
I have the next Code:
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Dim SqlQuery = New StringBuilder
Dim LstResults As New List(Of StoreDate)

SqlQuery.Append("searh something ")

Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR)
    Conn.Open()
    Using Cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlQuery.ToString, Conn)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Param1)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Param2)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", Param3)
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While Reader.Read()
                LstResults.Add(New StoreDate(Reader!Store, Reader!Date))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    Conn.Close()
End Using

If LstResults.Count > 0 Then
    Try
        Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR)
            Conn.Open()
            For Each Result As StoreDate In LstResults
                Store = Result.Store
                Date = Result.Date
                Using Cmd = New SqlCommand("STORE_PROCEDURE", Conn)
                    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateStore)
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", Tienda)
                    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            Conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        log("Error: " & ex.Message, alog)
    End Try
End If

SqlQuery.Clear()
LstResults.Clear()
Try
    SqlQuery.Append("do another search ")
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR)
        Conn.Open()
        Using Cmd = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery.ToString, Conn)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Param1)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Param2)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", Param3)
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While Reader.Read()
                    LstResults.Add(New StoreDate(Reader!Store, Reader!Date))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        Conn.Close()
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    log("Error: " & ex.Message , alog)
    Environment.Exit(ex.HResult)
End Try

But when it gets to the second datareader, I'm getting the error :"there is already a datareader associated with this command which must be closed first" which does not make sense to me, "Using" is supposed to dispose the objects right after it finishes, is it not? Am I missing something dumb here? I hope someone may help me, I've reach a death end on my own.
the only change I've made has been switching from a datatable to the list, StoreDate is the next simple class, but has nothing to do with the error, it comes out after hitting the second  "Using Reader As SqlDataReader"
Public Class StoreDate
    Private _Store As String
    Private _Date As DateTime


    Public Property Store As String
        Get
            Return _Store
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Store = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Date As DateTime
        Get
            Return _Date
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            _Date = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal Store As String, ByVal Date As DateTime)
        _Store = Store
        _Date = Date
    End Sub

End Class

UPDATE 1
As Suggested, I left only one connection open, and just to be sure, switched to a datatable like this:
'Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
'    While Reader.Read()
'        LstStoreDate.Add(New StoreDate(Reader!Store, Reader!Date))
'    End While
'End Using
TblStoreDate.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader())

but keep getting the same error after getting to "TblStoreDate.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader()"... I suppose this gives me a clue for what to search, just have to figure out what clue is that
UPDATE 2
out of desesperation, I switched the using blocks to the so call bad practice:
try
catch
Finally
Reader.Close (when applies)
Cmd.Dispose
Conn.Close
end try

For any reason beyond my comprehension, this approach seems to be working well so I'll leave it like that.
Thank you for your time everyone :)

There's something wrong in your post (maybe), you have these: Store = Result.Store Fecha = Result.Date, never used (you have other variables there) and SqlSetProcesos appears from nowhere, while you should be using the command previously created. See that you have posted the actual code -- You probably just need one open connection for all the queries, then close it when done. Don't need to call Close() either with a Using statement

Hi Jimi. for the Fecha = Result.Date, I translated the code to english and I miss that line, as for the SqlSetProcesos I renamed it to cmd, but since I comment it for testing porpuses, I forgot to make that change.
Ill try with just one connection and post an update. Thank you for your answer

If you set Option Strict On for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) does Visual Studio point out any problems to you?

(Incidentally, using Auto-Implemented Properties saves a lot of typing and space.)

Whenever I see someone run a query from .NET, just to loop over the results to run another query for each item, that's a sign you should re-factor to do it all in SQL in the first place. This can almost always be written to use another JOIN or at least a stored procedure. This will be significantly less code and run so much faster you wouldn't believe.

But the Finally block, at least, is not bad practice, as long as you really do use the Finally to close things up. It's just more verbose. The bad practice would be calling .Close() in an unprotected way that might leak an open connection if there's an exception.

My main suggestions is this should ALL be in SQL: send one (large) command string to the server. If you're running a query, just to loop through the result to send another query to the database for each row, and nothing else, you'll be amazed how much less code and how much faster the program will be if you let it all happen in the server.
This is true even if the only change is using a cursor and WHILE loop on the server, but that's not really what I mean. This can practically always be addressed by an additional JOIN or using a SELECT query as the source for an INSERT or UPDATE. If there's a stored procedure call, look into what the procedure is doing and use the information to build this into a larger query.
It makes me sad just how much memory the original code is needlessly wasting.
This will side step the issue from the question, so you don't need to worry about the connection for a second query or datareader at all.

But looking at the VB code we can see, I also see room for improvement in this excerpt:
Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR)
    Conn.Open()
    For Each Result As StoreDate In LstResults
        Store = Result.Store
        Date = Result.Date
        Using Cmd = New SqlCommand("STORE_PROCEDURE", Conn)
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateStore)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", Tienda)
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
    Conn.Close()
End Using

Normally we want our SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects to be single-purpose and short-lived. But when you need a tight loop like this, running effectively the same code, this is an opportunity to re-use the same SqlCommand object, so the connection only needs to Open() once and we don't have to keep re-allocating new command and parameter objects:
Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR),
      Cmd As New SqlCommand("STORE_PROCEDURE", Conn)

    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    ' Use actual types and sizes for the parameters here to match the database!
    Dim dp = Cmd.Paramters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    Dim sp = Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Store", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)

    Conn.Open()
    For Each Result As StoreDate In LstResults
        dp.Value = Result.Date
        sp.Value = Result.Store
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using

This will definitely help performance (though not as much as writing a complete SQL script). It might also help the question, on the chance the implied Cmd.Dispose() block was also breaking the SqlConnection object.
We can further improve on this by running it inside the first query, which avoids a bunch of copying (and allocating objects) for a list:
SqlQuery.Append("searh something ")
Using Conn As New SqlConnection(CONSTR),
      Cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlQuery.ToString(), Conn)

    ' The types here are just examples.
    ' Use actual types and sizes from the database!
    ' This often doesn't matter, but when it does it really can make a HUGE difference.
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Integer).Value =  Param1
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = Param2
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Param
    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    Conn.Open()
    
    Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' Can have multiple things talking to the database at a time
        ' Just beware of deadlocks, if you're updating back into the same tables
        Using Conn2 As New SqlConnection(CONSTR),
              Cmd2 As New SqlCommand("STORE_PROCEDURE", Conn2)

            Cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Cmd2.CommandTimeout = 0

            Dim dp = Cmd.Paramters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
            Dim sp = Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Store", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)

            Conn2.Open()
            While Reader.Read()
                dp.Value = Reader!Date
                ds.Value = Reader!Store
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End While
            Reader.Close() ' Reader.Dispose() is *NOT* formally documented to close the reader, still should call this manually. A finally block would be even better
    End Using
End Using

But this last option has the potential for dead locks if the outer query is locking the same table or rows needed for an inner query.
